# How to add notification icon on the Android phone status bar?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification-bar

I am new to Android programming and I need help. If any of you has a simple example of adding (icon/message) notification on the Phone and when clicked it restores back the application to its state. The purpose is the user could open any other application without exiting my app. Just like AIRDROID do.

I created an application where the user can login and do some tasks. But when I click the HOME it exits the application, and the user will have to login again. (Saving user/pass is not ideal for my project).

Anyone has a link/example/suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorials,hope it helps :) - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e74z0_Z5QWI&feature=relmfu

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.